# How do I implement SSL and CGIHTTPServer in Python 2.7? (SSL Error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, webserver

I'm trying to implement an SSL wrapped socket and CGIHTTPServer from BaseHTTPServer in Python 2.7. I had this working with the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler but I need to include CGI functionality.

The commented code is from previous iterations of this as I've been trying to solve the problem. If 
`ServerClass = HTTPServer` (see `run()`), I get `(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)`. If I use `ServerClass = SecureHTTPServer`, I can load pages on port 80 but I get connection resets on 443.

I'd greatly appreciate the help in getting an SSL-enabled Web Server with CGI support!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket, os, sys
from SocketServer import BaseServer
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import *
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from OpenSSL import SSL


class SecureHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass):
        BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, HandlerClass)
        Context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
        pem = 'C:\SERV\cert.pem'
        Context.use_privatekey_file(pem)
        Context.use_certificate_file(pem)
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(Context, socket.socket(self.address_family,self.socket_type))
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()

class SecureHTTPRequestHandler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ['/cgi']


    #def setup(self):
        #self.connection = self.request
        #self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
        #self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)

def run(HandlerClass = SecureHTTPRequestHandler,ServerClass = SecureHTTPServer):
    server_address = ('localhost', 443)
    handler = CGIHTTPRequestHandler
    server = ServerClass(server_address, handler)
    sa = server.socket.getsockname()

    try:
        print "Server SSL HTTPS on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
        server.serve_forever()

    except:
        server.socket.closed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: http://www.farville.com/15-line-python-https-cgi-server/